# How to isolate a device on a network

Tags: nat, ieee-802.11

I'm trying to isolate a device on the network so it can't access my router's admin interface.
Is there a device that can connect to my main network over wifi then have maybe a NAT to only give internet access to devices plugged into or connected over wifi to this intermediate device?
If it can be small and portable the better.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the router model? Most routers will let you configure ACLs to prevent access from specific devices, or only allow access from certain devices.

Comment: ...or eliminate the device/person!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the mac address of the device that you want to isolate, and put it on your router, blocking or filtering the access to the admin console. That is a basic security function on networks devices.